# How to install julia packages offline

Tags: julia

I'd like to use Julia on a computer which is disconnected from the Internet.
Is there simple procedure to download a package and then install it offline?

Comment: which package do you need?  you might face "dependency hell" when you try to install some package like Gadfly, Images...

Comment: I try to install "DataStructures", which should not be the most difficult to install as it doesn't seem to have that much dependencies.

Comment: there are only [`Compat`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl/releases) and [`Docile`](https://github.com/MichaelHatherly/Docile.jl/releases) on the list. download the latest released zip archives and then copy these three folders to `~/.julia/v0.X/Compat`/`Docile`/`Datastructures` as Reza suggested.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use PackageCompiler.jl to generate a sysimage for one or more Julia environments. If there are no conflicts between dependencies, you could include everything in a single sysimage and allow users to import them as needed in offline mode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800608/18431399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely, its possible.

`Pkg.dir() # => get you the package installation path`

check the `pkg.julialang.org/` address to get the right package and click on its `github` link, then you can download a zip archive from github.com and extract it into `Pkg.dir()`
**BUT you may taking yourself into trouble**
because you must do many optional things manually, e.g.:

- rename folder to remove `.jl`
- `build` steps
- install all related packages

I think a better way is to install Pkgs on a connected machine and then copy `Pkg.dir()` contents from that machine, to your system. this approach would works well only if both machines are of the same architecture (cpuX os julia-version).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought of the second solution, however I don't have a second similar machine to install my package first.
What do you exactly call "build steps"?

Comment: Julia source do not need a `build` phase to run but some packages have dependencies that need to be `build` on client machine, normally when you use Pkg manager to add a package it does many of the installation steps automatically,ref: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/pkg/#Base.Pkg.build , https://github.com/JuliaLang/BinDeps.jl

Comment: Before start downloading a pkg, check `REQUIRE` file in package root to see if it needs another module to run, also you can check `deps` folder for any build scripts.

Comment: Thanks Julia's LLVM-based just-in-time (JIT) compiler, many of Julia packages could be copy from one system to another and run normally without any difficulty.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything works perfectly, at least with DataStructures.