# Using Julia package manager offline

Tags: julia

We recently decided to make Julia Language available on our cluster systems. The cluster system is not able to connect to the internet. 
Is there any way to download all Julia packages and make them available for our different users to install and use them offline?

Another option that we have is a system that can connect to the internet temporarily, but it is always connected to the main cluster system. Is there any way to use this system as a mirror for the Julia packages or not?

We want to use "Julia 1.0.1".

our cluster operation system is: "CentOS 5.5

notes: I have seen the question asked before  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751848/how-to-install-julia-packages-offline), but it is for Julia 0.6 and a single package that will be copied by hand. I want that user uses the `Pkg.add <pkgName>` command but instead of the internet, the package manager gets the packages from our offline system.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: xref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/using-julia-package-manager-offline/17773

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a mirror locally using https://github.com/sunoru/PkgMirrors.jl . However many packages have binary dependency and need Internet access during building.

Comment: in Julia it is easy to reattach all packages via the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`. If you have Internet on one node and all nodes are identical you could use it as "installation & compilation node" and then replicate the contents to other servers in your cluster.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I have a system that can be attached to the internet temporarily. I get the packages but how can the packages be visible to all users. I show the path to Julia with activate /..../v1.0 but it says there are some missing packages and tries to download them from GitHub

Comment: I would try This: 1. Attach machine A to the internet. 2. `export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/my/package/folder"`. 3. `julia`. 4. Install whatever you need. 5. In the Julia package manager run `(v1.0) pkg> precompile` to precompile everything. 6. Copy "/my/package/folder" to machine B (without internet). 7. Run on machine B: `export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/my/package/folder"` before running `julia`. If machine A and B have the same hardware configuration this should work.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel  Thanks for your help. It works fine, but it raises a bigger problem. The solution works very well for only one user. we are a High-performance computing center with hundreds of users. Imagine How much space will it take to copy all the packages for each user. do you know any solution for this problem? Is it a way to have a shared repo for all different users?

Comment: As far as I know Julia uses `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` to store all compiled module files. As long as they are not compiled (that no new modules are added to Julia installation) it should be possible to share them in read-only mode across many users (I have not tested in though).

Comment: Now regarding the size: the main reason for huge size of `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` is the Python installation. Bu here it is easy. Simply do not use the inbuilt Python!. This can be achieved by setting ENV["PYTHON"] Julia variable *before* running Pkg.add("PyCall"). This will allow you to use an external Python Anaconda and I am pretty sure there are already many recipes how to share that across large user bases.

Comment: please look at this: [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/using-julia-package-manager-offline/17773/6?u=alirezamecheng)

Answer (score 1):

**Caution:**
*Side effects are not known!

May please be tested properly before put into production!*

a) Collect the required packages along with their dependent packages in compiled form, put them in folder, stdlib (for example: /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/shared/julia/stdlib/v1.1/)

b) add stdlib path to environment variables, JULIA_DEPOT_PATH and JULIA_LOAD_PATH

Answer (score 0):

The following is a crosspost of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800608/18431399

---

[PackageCompiler.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) seems like the best tool for using modern Julia (v1.8) on secure systems. The following approach requires a build server with the same architecture as the deployment server, something your institution probably already uses for developing containers, etc.

1. [Build a sysimage with PackageCompiler's create_sysimage()](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/sysimages.html)
2. Upload the build (sysimage and depot) along with the Julia binaries to the secure system
3. Alias a script to `julia`, similar to the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeu -o pipefail

unset JULIA_LOAD_PATH

export JULIA_PROJECT=/Path/To/Project
export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/Path/To/Depot
export JULIA_PKG_OFFLINE=true

/Path/To/julia -J/Path/To/sysimage.so "$@"
```

I've been able to run a research pipeline on my institution's secure system, for which there is a [public version of the approach.](https://github.com/bcbi/SIEGE)